# Why did Dhritarashtra give Draupadi boons?

Tags: mahabharata, draupadi, boon, dhritarashtra

I understand that there were some bad omens that led dhritarashtra to give draupadi the boons. But why did this happen and what were the omens?

It seems more logical to keep the wealth and kill the pandavas if they make too much noise. Why didn't dhritarashtra do this?

And a tangential question, why were pandavas exiled? It seems like a round about way of getting rid of them. Wouldn't it be easier to just silence them?

*this is regarding the dice game and the fallout*

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! What do u mean by "silence them"?

Comment: I was thinking of a game of throne/red wedding type of thing but that was just a tangential question, not too important.